# pausing device without visual cues

Tags: sensors

I'm doing a competition that requires our device to pause and stop midway on a pole. The device carries an increasing load (chain). The midway point is marked with a slight score mark (which we don't believe will be that noticeable). The device is supposed to travel up on the outside of the pole without pausing, pause on the way down and again on the way up, not pause going down the second time and then stop midway going up again.

I don't have experience with programming sensors and motors so, while I have ideas about how to do this, I don't quite know how to actually program this. There's a cap on the top I can use to switch direction of travel but the end of the pipe is open. I'm thinking of using either height off the floor or the weight of the chain as a constant to mark position along the pole. I'm having trouble finding inexpensive sensors so I don't have specifics.

Right now, I'm toying with the idea of using the switch at the top as sort of an on/off for the pausing/not pausing code. Alternatively, I can use the constant measurement (height/weight) to count the cycles and switch on the code that way. Is this an effective way of doing this? I'm looking at a raspberry pi to control everything.

Comment: What is a device in your context?

Comment: The device is supposed to climb the outside of the tube without external interference.